# Simplify nested loops with condition

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab program with 5 nested

```
for
```

loops and a

```
if
```

condition like this:

```
for x0=1:N
    for y0=1:N
        for k=1:N
            for x1=1:N
                for y1=1:N
                    if ~((y1-x1>N/2)||(x1-y1>N/2)) && ~((y0-x0>N/2)||(x0-y0>N/2))
                        A(x0,y0)=A(x0,y0)+2^(k*((x0-y0)+(x1-y1)))*B(x1,y1)
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

where A and B are two matrices. How can I make this program run faster?

I've tried to use meshgrid but it seems doesn't work because there's a

```
if
```

condition.

Comment: I think this depends a lot on the details of your condition, and perhaps your statement. Can you make a representative example? Is it a simple math check, or a complex function call?

Comment: @Pursuit Ok, I've edited them.

Comment: I don't have time to check how you calculate `A`, but your `if` statement can be expressed as: `if abs(y1-x1)<=N/2 && abs(x0-y0)<=N/2` which is a bit more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Lets be smart about loops and conditions first, as you are using the loop indices as condition variables.

We start with
`~(y1-x1>N/2)||(x1-y1>N/2)`, or **way** clearer, `abs(y1-x1)<N/2`.

Instead of having an `if` condition, why not enforce `y1` to be in range, always?

The last loop can be written as `y1=max(x1-N/2,1):min(x1+N/2,N)`, and thus the entirety of the first part of the `if` condition is not needed. We can do the same for the other variables, of course:

```
for x0=1:N
    for y0=max(x0-N/2,1):min(x0+N/2,N)
        for k=1:N
            for x1=1:N
                for y1=max(x1-N/2,1):min(x1+N/2,N)
                     A(x0,y0)=A(x0,y0)+2^(k*((x0-y0)+(x1-y1)))*B(x1,y1)
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Now, for clarity, lets reshuffle and vectorize that `k`. There is no need for it to be the middle loop, in fact, its only feature as the middle loop is to confuse the person reading the code. But aside from that, there is no need for it to be a loop either.

```
k=1:N;
for x0=1:N
    for y0=max(x0-N/2,1):min(x0+N/2,N)
         for x1=1:N
             for y1=max(x1-N/2,1):min(x1+N/2,N)
                  A(x0,y0)=A(x0,y0)+sum(2.^(k*((x0-y0)+(x1-y1))))*B(x1,y1)
             end
         end
    end
end
```

Now, is this faster?

**No.** MATLAB is really good at optimizing your code, so it is not faster. But at least its way way clearer, so I guess you got that going for you. But you need it faster! Well.... I am not sure you can. You have a 5 nested loops, that is just super slow. I don't think you can `meshgrid` this, even without the conditions, because you intermingle all loops. `meshgrid` is good when well, you do operations on a mesh grid, but in your case you use all `x1,y1` for every `x0,y0` and thus its not a mesh operation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized solution:

```
x0 = (1:N).';
y0 = 1:N;
x1 = (1:N).';
y1 = 1:N;
k = reshape(1:N, 1, 1, N);
conditiona = ~((y0-x0 > N/2) | (x0-y0 > N/2));
conditionb = ~((y1-x1 > N/2) | (x1-y1 > N/2));
a = 2 .^ (k .* (x0-y0)) .* conditiona;
b = 2 .^ (k .* (x1-y1)) .* B .* conditionb;
bsum = squeeze(sum(sum(b, 1) ,2));
A = A + reshape(reshape(a, [] , N) * bsum ,N ,N);
```

Note that two 3D arrays `a` and `b` are created that may/may not require a lot of memory. In such a case you need to loop over `k`. For example in the first iteration set `k` to `1:5`. In the second iteration set it to `6:10` and so on. You need to addv the result of each iteration to the previous iteration to form the final `A`.

**Explanation**

This function can be vectorized by implicit expansion (that is more efficient than using `meshgrid`) and using element-wise operators like `.^` and `.*` instead of `^` and `*` operators. As a result a 5D  array is created (because we have 5 loop variables) that should be summed over 3-5th dimensions to produce the final 2D matrix. However that may require a lot of memory. Another point is that functions that contains the sum of products usually can be written as efficient matrix multiplication.
The expression:

```
2^(k*((x0-y0)+(x1-y1)))*B(x1,y1);
```

can be written as:

```
2 .^ (k .* (x0-y0)) .* 2 .^ (k .* (x1-y1)) .* B(x1, y1) 
------- a --------     -------------  b  ---------------
```

that is the multiplication of two sub-expressions that each has 3 dimensions, because each contains just 3 loop variables. So the 5D problem is reduced to 3D.
The `if` condition  has also two sub-expressions that each can be multiplied by `a` and `b` sub-expressions:

```
conditiona = ~((y0-x0 > N/2) | (x0-y0 > N/2));
conditionb = ~((y1-x1 > N/2) | (x1-y1 > N/2));
a = 2 .^ (k .* (x0-y0)) .* conditiona;
b = 2 .^ (k .* (x1-y1)) .* B .* conditionb;
```

A for loop can be formed just by using two loop variables `x0` and `y0`:

```
for x0=1:N
    for y0=1:N
        A(x0,y0)=A(x0,y0)+ sum(sum(sum(a(x0,x0, :) .* b, 3), 2), 1);
        %or simply A(x0,y0)=A(x0,y0)+ sum(a(x0,x0, :) .* b, "all");
    end
end
```

That can be simplified to the following loop by precomputing sum of `b`:

```
bsum = sum(sum(b, 1) ,2);
% bsum = sum(b ,[1, 2]);
for x0=1:N
    for y0=1:N
        A(x0,y0)=A(x0,y0)+ sum(a(x0,x0, :) .* bsum, 3);
        % or as vector x vector multiplication 
        % A(x0,y0)=A(x0,y0)+ squeeze(a(x0,x0, :)).' * squeeze(bsum);
    end
end
```

Here the loop can be prevented by using the matrix x vector multiplication:

```
A = A + reshape(reshape(a, [] , N) * bsum ,N ,N);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** this solution may not be faster under Matlab, because the execution engine can optimise the loops in the original code. (It does provide a speedup under Octave.)

One trick to deal with `if` statements within loops is to turn the `if` statement (or part of it) into a logical matrix. You can then multiply the logical matrix *elementwise* by the matrix of values you are adding in each step. A `false` value will evaluate to zero and will not change the result.

This only works if each element can be computed independently of the others.
It will generally make the actual calculation line slower, but in Matlab this is often outweighed by the huge speed improvement from the the removal of the for loops.

In your example, we can use this idea with meshgrid to remove the loops over `x0` and `y0`.
The calculation line needs to become an elementwise matrix caluclation, so elementwise operators `.*`, `.^` and `|` replace `*`, `^` and `|`.

```
% Warning: Y0 and X0 are swapped in this example
[Y0, X0] = meshgrid(1:N,1:N);

% Create a logical matrix which represents part of the if statement
C = ~((Y0-X0>N/2) | (X0-Y0>N/2));

for k=1:N
    for x1=1:N
        for y1=1:N
           if ~((y1-x1>N/2)||(x1-y1>N/2))
               % Multiply by C elementwise
               A = A + C.*2.^(k*((X0-Y0)+(x1-y1)))*B(x1,y1);
           end
        end
    end
end
```

You could even take this concept further and remove more loops using multidemensional `ndgrid`s, but it becomes more complex (you have to start summing over dimensions) and the multidimensional arrays become unwieldy if `N` is large.

Note: be careful with index order. `meshgrid` defines `y` as rows and `x` as columns, so matrix indexing is `A(y,x)` but you are using `A(x,y)`. So to make your example work I've switched x and y in the output of `meshgrid`.

Comment: “the huge speed improvement from the the removal of the for loops.” This was true 20 years ago, but hasn’t been true since, MATLAB now has a JIT that makes loops almost as fast as built-in methods. Loop code sometimes is faster than vectorized code if the vectorization requires large intermediate arrays, such as you build here with meshgrid. Did you  time your code to ensure it actually is faster?

Comment: Did you time this? In my example, I provide a similar improvement and indeed its not faster (in fact marginally slower).

Comment: Fair enough, I tested this on Octave (as I don't have access to Matlab) and it gave 300x speedup on N=20. I used to get similar speedups on Matlab a few years ago but I guess the Matlab JIT compiler has improved a lot in the last few years.